# I'm running a python code and the variables come out as "not defined"

Tags: python, spyder

I'm working on a acoustic recognition project, where we are using python and scikit-maad.

I'm following this script, specifically util.py https://github.com/juansulloa/putumayo_soundmarks/blob/master/scripts/utils.py

The problems start even when creating the new environment, I did import the anfibia environment listed there but had to do further package installation manually.

After doing that, when trying to run the script, the variables defined within the functions were not created but the code still ran, when I wanted to see the outputs it always said " xvariable not defined " and the code runs "successfully" without any errors.

I ran every function independently but that didn't work, I also noticed that as I listed the packages in the enviroment, os was not listed, and the first problem is it didn't recognize listdir, I fixed that using listdir_pattern but flist still showed as not defined. I'm expecting to be able to see the variables, I can provide data to help run this.

Any kind of help is very well received, I'm running this in anaconda using spyder by the way, thank you.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code and include that inline (not a link!) in your question. Also, include both the actual and expected output from it. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You cannot run the `utils.py` file as a stand alone script since it only defines a bunch of functions, but never calls any of them. For us to help you, we need to see the code that you are running.

Comment: Which script are you trying to run?  Some of the scripts in that folder are runnable, but some are just libraries.